# Error while runing sudo command in ubuntu installed inside Windows 10?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-10, sudo, ubuntu-18.04

My ubuntu 18.04 install successly from store. After that I tried two command which gives me error as follows

```
sudo apt update
```

> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80] Err:2
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease   Connection failed
>   [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   bionic-updates InRelease   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
>   Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done All
>   packages are up to date. W: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection
>   failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] W: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease 
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] W: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease 
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80] W: Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease 
>   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80] W: Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

```
sudo apt install postgresql # Install PostgreSQL
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done E: Unable to locate package postgresql

I am trying odoo12 development on windows 10 with WSL ubuntu. I want to install postgres and odoo dependencies in this linux subsystem installed in windows 10. Please help me.

Comment: Looks like you do not have internet or the firewall is blocking outgoing access to the Ubuntu repositories

Comment: I got kaspersky installed on my windows but its not showing any alert as they do while block something ?

Comment: No reason for Kaspersky to block Ubuntu's servers. That's not likely to be the problem. But obviously, as `apt update` fails so badly, the subsequent `apt-get` is entirely pointless.

Comment: @MSalters is there any work around to solve this issue. I dont have any hands on experience in linux operating system !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was with kaspersky when I exit the program and run bash commands it works. I got the answer from this link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076242/running-sudo-apt-get-update-returns-connection-errors

thank you all for the helps